# How long should it take for a moderator attention flag to be reviewed?

Tags: support, flags, moderation

I've flagged a few questions in the past and they were reviewed by a moderator very quickly (within an hour or so).

A couple of days ago I flagged this question: [Redundant relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671291/redundant-relationship) as being a cross-post on SO and DBA.SE.  It still hasn't been reviewed.

Given my experience in the past, I'm worried that my flag has "fallen between the cracks".  Is a two day lag normal? (or is it to be expected now because of some extraordinary backlog?)

I'm wondering what is the best way to make sure my flag gets reviewed?

Comment: We haven't gotten to that flag yet.  I'm sorry about that.  I will initiate the appropriate floggings, and continue them until the response time improves.

Comment: In other news, my raise should be coming through soon.  It's a 100% increase over what I was being paid before.

Comment: To answer the title: 6 to 8 weeks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the moderator dashboard, the average handling time for flags handled in the past month is about eight hours.  This is an increase of about 1 hour over the average from about six months ago.

There are currently 314 flags in the queue.  I'm working on some of them now.  We field roughly a thousand flags per day.

Also, note that flags may linger in the 10K queue for awhile before they get kicked up to the moderator queue for processing.  If several 10K users spent a few minutes each day fielding just a few of these flags per day, it would greatly reduce the wait time.

Regarding your linked question, we don't have a way to merge cross-posts.

Comment: Robert - Thank you for letting me know how things work.  Don't mistake my question for whip-cracking.  Rather I was just worried that something was broken.  I've only been on SO for a year now and I've still got lots to learn.  Please feel free to use me as a character reference for your next salary doubling.  Would it make sense to migrate the question to DBA.SE and let the mods over there merge the two questions?

Comment: I suggest you cast a flag at DBA.SE requesting deletion.

Comment: I've seen the 10k queue peaking above 500 over the last few days. Very demoralising, so I completely sympathise with Robert...

Comment: @Benjol Yep. Used to be 100-ish when I got to it in January, 150 was very high, 200 extreme. Now, I haven't seen it below 300 since I don't remember when.

Comment: Do you have stats for custom flags as well? While my sample base is pretty small, it feels like the delay for those increased *a lot*.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry about that.  I'm on vacation!

Comment: We won't hold it against you. Or we will. I'm just not sure which! ;)

Comment: You get your ass back here right now. We didn't vote for you and allocate you a generous $0 salary so you can take fancy vacations, man.

Comment: -1 and Flagged - because jealousy makes you nasty :P