# How many flags are needed to kick a flag from 10k queue to Mod. queue?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, 10k-tools

Because of this question

[*How long should it take for a moderator attention flag to be reviewed?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133358/how-long-should-it-take-for-a-moderator-attention-flag-to-be-reviewed)

and because of the large amount of flags in the 10k queue during the last weeks, I am wondering how many flags are needed to kick a flag into the moderator queue?

I am spending very often some time to review flags in the 10k queue and because of the high amount of open flags I want to use my 49 flags efficiently.

Normally, if a flag has already 3 or 4 additional flags, I will not add my flag and use my flags on flags that have none or only 1 additional flag.

Is this behaviour useful? I mean are flags with already 4 additional flags already sufficiently handled or is it useful to add a fifth or maybe a eights flag?

If it is no difference for a mod if a question has 4 or 6 flags it would maybe make sense to remove flags from the 10k queue, when they made it to the mod queue.

Comment: Are you regularly running out of flags? If not, why is this a concern?

Comment: If I would add my flags to everything in the 10k queue (that is correctly flagged), I would run out of flags regularly.

Comment: I would also like a bit more clarity on how this works. @The, it's not a question or running out, but of how much effect is the effort I'm putting in going to have?

Comment: I always assumed it wasn't just "how many?" but "who flagged them and what's their weight?"

Comment: Maybe more flags should be provided for "re-flagging"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this behaviour useful? I mean are flags with already 4 additional flags already sufficiently handled or is it useful to add a fifth or maybe a eights flag?

Yes, it's useful. Flagging a post 4, 6, 10, or even 94 times does not mean that anything is "handled". It's not handled until either you take action to correct the problem yourself (such as editing or voting to close), or a moderator sees the flag and takes the appropriate action. So adding your own flags of agreement (or disagreement!) is always useful.

Of course, how you choose to distribute your daily allotment of flags is, as always, a matter of personal preference. If there are some flagged posts that have received relatively little attention from the community, and you want to maximize the likelihood that these flags will be processed rapidly, then adding a confirmatory flag of your own makes good sense.

Additionally, if you're known by the system to be a *consistently* helpful flagger, then things you flag will be given more weight and shown higher in the queue. It's basically a trust system—if we have reason to trust your judgment based on past history, then we'll give your complaints more attention. If you've been known to  repeatedly [cry wolf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_Who_Cried_Wolf), we tend to postpone handling your flags to a time when we're less busy.

> If it is no difference for a mod if a question has 4 or 6 flags it would maybe make sense to remove flags from the 10k queue, when they made it to the mod queue.

Piling on flags *definitely* makes a difference for moderators. If a particular post has been flagged by 8–10 different users, that's a much stronger mandate than if it has been flagged by 3–4 different users. That, in turn, reduces the amount of time mods have to spend gawking at each flag. If it's been well-vetted by the community, a quick confirmatory glance is all that's required.

Answer (score 5):

Every flagged post present in 10k queue will be visible to Mods. There's no cutoff point at which it moves from 10k queue to Mod queue.

> Normally, if a flag has already 3 or 4 additional flags, I will not
>   add my flag and use my flags on flags that have none or only 1
>   additional flag.
>
> Is this behaviour useful? I mean are flags with already 4 additional
>   flags already sufficiently handled or is it useful to add a fifth or
>   maybe a eights flag?

If a post is quite bad, you should add a flag - the number of flags makes a difference in which the flags are presented in the queue (amongst other factors)

Comment: There are some flags (I think *only* close question flags) that appear in the 10k queue before the diamond mod queue.  These should get moved over to the diamond mod queue either after a timeout period of a few days, or after they get enough flags without being handled by 10k users.  I don't know if this is an SO-only feature or not.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I haven't seen that in [su]..

Comment: @BilltheLizard, maybe question with closed flags should be shown in the list of question with closed votes but with a close vote count of 0

Comment: @IanRingrose That's a good idea.  There's quite a gap between the 10k users that can see the flag queue and the 3k users who can vote to close.