# Is it appropriate to flag a post again, for the same reason?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

I've identified [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619005/developer-documenation-for-previous-releases-of-the-chromium-google-chrome) to be an duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453108/where-can-i-see-which-chrome-extensions-api-is-valid-for-which-chrome-version). Because the tag does not have many active users, I decided to raise a moderator attention flag (from past experience, I learned that my own close vote will rarely result in the question to be closed).

The flag was deemed `helpful`, but the question is still not closed.

1. Did a non-diamond moderator review the flag? [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133359) suggests that the flag can also be handled by 10k users.
2. If the duplicate reason is obvious, is it allowed to raise another flag?

In this particular case, the immediately OP [agreed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619005/developer-documenation-for-previous-releases-of-the-chromium-google-chrome#comment17012950_12619005) that the question is a duplicate. Would another flag be justified here?

Comment: When my flag was deemed helpful, I saw two vote closes. Surprisingly, now the question is closed, I see that the second vote comes from the OP, not from the one who reviewed my flag. What happened here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the question, the flag was handled by users voting to close the question. No actual moderator looked at your flag.

Let the community do its thing. Moderators are really there to be the last line of moderation. We don't scale nearly as well as the community does.

If a few days goes by and nothing happens, flag it again. Sometimes though, just understand that a moderator may mark your flag as helpful, but do nothing about it. That's their prerogative.

Sometimes I'll mark a flag as helpful but not act on it if:

- The Question/answer is already being moderated by the community (through close votes)
- There is ample room for reasonable people to disagree (also known as letting the community duke it out)
- The post has the attention of people (who are already editing it).  It doesn't make sense to take action on a post that everyone can see is in the process of being improved.
- Comments were left for the OP and the OP has responded favorably to the suggestions posed