# What is the correct procedure for getting mods attention?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation

I had a query about my account that required a moderator to look at something and give me some feedback.

Not wanting to make it public on meta, I did what some other posts had suggested and flagged one of my own questions for moderator attention, then explained my problem.

However, it's been two days now and there has been no response, even though subsequent flags have been actioned.

Did I do the right thing? Should I be more patient?

Comment: It's probably that you should be more patient. Complex situations may be complex to solve and require investigation from people other than just mods, which takes time... I'll let a mod confirm though :-).

Comment: Thanks @benisuǝqbackwards - I'll be more patient then - it's just that [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133358/218740) implied it would be a matter of hours rather than days. Really just wanted to know if I should have posted to meta instead.

Comment: You could also try highlighting the need on the [contact page](http://stackoverflow.com/contact)

Comment: A few months ago custom flags took around two days on stackoverflow, now it seems to take over two weeks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your flag is still "active" meaning it hasn't been actioned.

There are currently nearly 1,000 flags awaiting moderator attention of which nearly 650 are in the "other" category - i.e. the ones that potentially take some time to resolve - which is the specific queue your flag is in.

That said your flag is also something that only an employee can resolve. This means that it will take additional time to resolve as we have to contact the team and they have to review the situation and see what, if anything, they can do.

As well as chat there is the [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page. However, that should only be used for serious issues.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's not serious enough to escalate, it sounds like I did the right thing and I'll just wait quietly until something happens.

Comment: Maybe SO should host another election cycle.

Comment: @Emrakul - the level is hight - but it's not constantly high. There will probably be an election in the new year.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to catch a moderator in the chat rooms.  Then you could at least raise the subject of your flag - which you should still do first.  As lkely as not, the matter is being looked at, I wouldn't want to be too pushy.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't think of that - I've never done chatting ...